# jQuery UI Trash Icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

With some help from users of this site, I've managed to put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/gallerytest2.php#/0) gallery page.

You'll see on the example page that I'm using a cross to allow a user to delete the image. The problem I'm encountering is in trying to change the icon to the jQuery UI 'trash' icon. I've found the icon in question which is `.ui-icon-trash` but I can't find any instructions on how to implement this into my page.

The piece of code which deals with the icon is as below:

```
 .galleria-thumbnails .btn-delete {    
          display: block;  
          position: absolute; bottom : 0px;   
          width: 80px;     
          height: 80px;    
          cursor: pointer;     
          background: url(cross.png) no-repeat bottom; }
```

I've tried changing `url(cross.png)` to `url(.ui-icon-trash)` and to `url(class=.ui-icon-trash)` without any success. I also, if possible like to centre the icon as opposed to it's current position of `off-centre`.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this, you must use HTML code like this :

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>
```

This will display the trash icon.

There isn't a "trash" picture as an icon file. All the icons are stored in one big "sprite" picture file, and then some CSS rules are applied to display only the requested icon.

Comment: Hi, @adrien, many thanks for replying to my post. Forgive me for asking, do I still in the `url` element of the code. I'm not really sure what to change. Kind regards

Comment: you do not need the `url` element in CSS anymore.

Comment: I'm really sorry for being so stupid, but I've change this `background: url(cross.png) no-repeat bottom; }` to this `background: <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>; }`. Could you tell me please where I've gone wrong, because the icon doesn't appear on screen. Once again apologies for asking. Kind regards

Comment: You don't want to add this line in your CSS file / style tag. Add it in your HTML code, just where you have the <img src="close.png"> tag

Comment: Hi @adrien, thank you for bearing with me on this. It's been a long day. I think I'll have to revisit this a little later because I just can't seem to get this to work. My apologies. Kind regards.

Comment: Hi @adrien. I've been back to this and added the line where I think you mean as below, but unfortunately I can't get this to work.

`$(".galleria-image").append(      
 "<span class='btn-delete'></span>");  
 $(".btn-delete").live("click", function() 
 {     var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img");      
 alert('Deleting image... ' + $(img).attr("src="<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>"));     return false; });`

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Try this : `$(".galleria-image").append( "<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); $(".btn-delete").live("click", function() { var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); alert('Deleting image... '); return false; });`

Comment: please don't spend anymore time on this. I think the issues I was experiencing were attributed to the image software I'm using, rather than your code. I've since added a new .png file which does the job fine. Once again many thanks for all your time and trouble. Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it jQuery way this is what you are looking for:

```
$(function () {
  $('.btn-delete').addClass('ui-icon-trash');
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to help me out with this. Through quite a bit of testing I was unable to get this to work, along with the other proposed solution. I think it was more an issue of the image software rather than your code. I've rectified the problem and added a .png file. This works well. Once again, many thanks and kind regards.